# Limit of Sequence Whose Elements Depend on Previous Elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was solving some exercises on limits, when I came across this problem:

> The point $C_1$ divides a segment $AB = l$ in half; the point $C_2$ divides a segment $AC_1$ in half; the point $C_3$ divides a segment $C_2C_1$ in half; the point $C_4$ divides $C_2C_3$ in half, and so on. Determine the limiting position of the point $C_n$ when $n \to \infty$.

I did successfully answer *this* particular exercise. However, it led me to a more general question.

**How do you evaluate the limit of a sequence whose elements depend on prior elements?** Sources on this topic are also welcome.

As another example, the Fibonacci sequence is one whose elements rely on prior elements (however, unlike the exercise above, there is no limit).

<sup>**Note:** I'd appreciate if nothing more advanced than limits are used. This exercise was found at the beginning of a calculus and analysis book, and all that I've covered so far are limits.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Show by induction:

$C_{2n}=C_2 ( \frac{3}{4})^{n-1}$ and $C_{2n+1}=C_1 ( \frac{3}{4})^{n}$ .

Hence $C_n \to 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote ???

Comment: Answer is $C_n \to \frac{1}{3}l$. Also, I didn't ask for the answer/solution to this particular problem. I wanted to know how to go about problems similar to these.